# Switching to NAV 2017: Printer List missing Client Name

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

We're having a problem with printer selection while migrating to NAV 2017 (from 5.0). The original method of listing printers (NavTools) is only giving the print server name and the other methods we tried ( `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters()`, `ManagementObjectSearcher('select * from win32_printer')` ) only give us a list of printer names and no way to get the client name. As users can connect via local client or remote desktop (and since certain users can have access to all thus connected printers) having more than just the name to go on is essential. Is there any other method to get printers with their client name intact?

**EDIT:**

I had a look in this NavTools code, and it gets the data from the registry. Apparently, the registry structure changed, and I haven't managed to find anything similar yet.

```
PrinterDriverData = HKLM.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\" + PrinterDeviceList.GetValue(pIndex) + "\PrinterDriverData")
Return PrinterDriverData.GetValue("ClientName")
```

Comment: On one client site we had to A) publicly share the (zebra) printer on the  computer it was installed with, B) install the drivers on each client computer/terminal server that wished to use the computer, finally C) from the Printer selection list add the following '\\printmachine\printer'.
It would be optimal to print directly from the server, however.

Comment: Our problem is that several users have their own printers with the same make (and thus name), so we have to choose between them by the client name they're attached to.